# Javascript split string on space or on quotes to array

Tags: javascript, regex, split

```
var str = 'single words "fixed string of words"';
var astr = str.split(" "); // need fix
```

I would like the array to be like this:

```
var astr = ["single", "words", "fixed string of words"];
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
str.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g)

//single, words, "fixed string of words"
```

Comment: this seems to split on '.' and '-' as well as spaces. This should probably be `str.match(/\S+|"[^"]+"/g)`

Comment: There's another problem with this, if it has to handle escaped quotes.  For example:

`'single words "fixed string of \"quoted\" words"'`

Even with Awalias' correction, this gives:

`["single", "words", ""fixed", "string", ""of", "words""]`

You'd need to handle escaped quotes, but not trip up and grab and escaped backslash.  I think it would eventually get more complicated than you'd really want to handle with a regexp.

Comment: @Awalias I have a better answer below. Your regex example actually should be /[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"/g.  Yours will still split on spaces in quoted areas.  I added an answer that fixes this and removes the quotation marks from the results like the OP asked for.

Comment: If you want to allow escaping the quotes, see [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031900).

Answer (score 43):

The accepted answer is not entirely correct.  It separates on non-space characters like . and - and leaves the quotes in the results.  The better way to do this so that it excludes the quotes is with capturing groups, like such:

```
//The parenthesis in the regex creates a captured group within the quotes
var myRegexp = /[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"/gi;
var myString = 'single words "fixed string of words"';
var myArray = [];

do {
    //Each call to exec returns the next regex match as an array
    var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
    if (match != null)
    {
        //Index 1 in the array is the captured group if it exists
        //Index 0 is the matched text, which we use if no captured group exists
        myArray.push(match[1] ? match[1] : match[0]);
    }
} while (match != null);
```

myArray will now contain exactly what the OP asked for:

```
single,words,fixed string of words
```

Comment: Works well, thank you. Just to say the 'i' switch looks to be redundant.

Comment: var myRegexp = [^\s"]+|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"/g ...allows for \" (escaped quotes within quotes)

Comment: I had posted a question asking the exact issue, later deleting it (no replies/answers) after a more dedicated search found this excellent answer.  As mentioned, the solution above does exactly as the OP asked (`'apple banana "nova scotia" "british columbia"'` >> `"apple", "banana", "nova scotia", "british columbia"` -- and I learned something new viz-a-viz JavaScript!  :-)

Comment: ideally you want to do it char by char, as there are two case scenarios that will break most of regex solutions: "text\"continue" and "text\\" continue "another text", like in case  of paths

Answer (score 12):

This uses a mix of split and regex matching.

```
var str = 'single words "fixed string of words"';
var matches = /".+?"/.exec(str);
str = str.replace(/".+?"/, "").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
var astr = str.split(" ");
if (matches) {
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        astr.push(matches[i].replace(/"/g, ""));
    }
}
```

This returns the expected result, although a single regexp should be able to do it all.

```
// ["single", "words", "fixed string of words"]
```

**Update**
And this is the improved version of the the method proposed by S.Mark

```
var str = 'single words "fixed string of words"';
var aStr = str.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g), i = aStr.length;
while(i--){
    aStr[i] = aStr[i].replace(/"/g,"");
}
// ["single", "words", "fixed string of words"]
```

Comment: There's a problem with the improved version, where if you use a non-word-character like "#" it will disappear.

Comment: This is a good answer, but if you want to do it all via regex and have the quotes removed, I added a new answer that does this and doesn't require looping through every result to strip out the quotes afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Here might be a complete solution:
https://github.com/elgs/splitargs

Answer (score 3):

ES6 solution supporting:

- Split by space except for inside quotes
- Removing quotes but not for backslash escaped quotes
- Escaped quote become quote
- Can put quotes anywhere

Code:

```
str.match(/\\?.|^$/g).reduce((p, c) => {
        if(c === '"'){
            p.quote ^= 1;
        }else if(!p.quote && c === ' '){
            p.a.push('');
        }else{
            p.a[p.a.length-1] += c.replace(/\\(.)/,"$1");
        }
        return  p;
    }, {a: ['']}).a
```

Output:

```
[ 'single', 'words', 'fixed string of words' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will split it into an array and strip off the surrounding quotes from any remaining string.

```js
const parseWords = (words = '') =>
    (words.match(/[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"/gi) || []).map((word) => 
        word.replace(/^"(.+(?="$))"$/, '$1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This soulution would work for both double (") and single (') quotes:

**Code**:

```js
str.match(/[^\s"']+|"([^"]*)"/gmi)

// ["single", "words", "fixed string of words"]
```

Here it shows how this regular expression would work: https://regex101.com/r/qa3KxQ/2

Answer (score 0):

Until I found @dallin 's answer (this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647776/1904943) I was having difficulty processing strings with a mix of unquoted and quoted terms / phrases, via JavaScript.

In researching that issue, I ran a number of tests.

As I found it difficult to find this information, I have collated the relevant information (below), which may be useful to others seeking answers on the processing in JavaScript of strings containing quoted words.

---

```js
let q = 'apple banana "nova scotia" "british columbia"';
```

**Extract [only] quoted words and phrases:**

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367126/how-can-i-get-a-substring-located-between-2-quotes
const r = q.match(/"([^']+)"/g);
console.log('r:', r)
// r: Array [ "\"nova scotia\" \"british columbia\"" ]
console.log('r:', r.toString())
// r: "nova scotia" "british columbia"

// ----------------------------------------

// [alternate regex] https://www.regextester.com/97161
const s = q.match(/"(.*?)"/g);
console.log('s:', s)
// s: Array [ "\"nova scotia\"", "\"british columbia\"" ]
console.log('s:', s.toString())
// s: "nova scotia","british columbia"
```

**Extract [all] unquoted, quoted words and phrases:**

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817646/javascript-split-string-on-space-or-on-quotes-to-array
const t = q.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g);
console.log('t:', t)
// t: Array(4) [ "apple", "banana", "\"nova scotia\"", "\"british columbia\"" ]
console.log('t:', t.toString())
// t: apple,banana,"nova scotia","british columbia"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817646/javascript-split-string-on-space-or-on-quotes-to-array
// [@dallon 's answer (this thread)] https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647776/1904943

var myRegexp = /[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"/gi;
var myArray = [];

do {
    /* Each call to exec returns the next regex match as an array. */
    var match = myRegexp.exec(q);    // << "q" = my query (string)
    if (match != null)
    {
        /* Index 1 in the array is the captured group if it exists.
         * Index 0 is the matched text, which we use if no captured group exists. */
        myArray.push(match[1] ? match[1] : match[0]);
    }
} while (match != null);

console.log('myArray:', myArray, '| type:', typeof(myArray))
// myArray: Array(4) [ "apple", "banana", "nova scotia", "british columbia" ] | type: object
console.log(myArray.toString())
// apple,banana,nova scotia,british columbia
```

**Work with a set (rather than an array):**

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965112/javascript-array-to-set
var mySet = new Set(myArray);
console.log('mySet:', mySet, '| type:', typeof(mySet))
// mySet: Set(4) [ "apple", "banana", "nova scotia", "british columbia" ] | type: object
```

**Iterating over set elements:**

```js
mySet.forEach(x => console.log(x));
/* apple
 * banana
 * nova scotia
 * british columbia
 */

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401216/iterate-over-set-elements
myArrayFromSet = Array.from(mySet);

for (let i=0; i < myArrayFromSet.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + ':', myArrayFromSet[i])
}
/*
 0: apple
 1: banana
 2: nova scotia
 3: british columbia 
 */
```

---

**Asides**

- The JavaScript responses above are from the FireFox Developer Tools (F12, from web page). I created a blank HTML file that calls a `.js` file that I edit with Vim, as my IDE. [Simple JavaScript IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132593/simple-javascript-ide/66376974#66376974)
- Based on my tests, the cloned set appears to be a deep copy. [Shallow-clone an ES6 Map or Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626070/shallow-clone-an-es6-map-or-set/66380544#66380544)

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the disappearing characters, too.  I think you can include them - for example, to have it include "+" with the word, use something like "[\w\+]" instead of just "\w".