# Split a string by whitespace, keeping quoted segments, allowing escaped quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have this regular expression to split strings by all whitespace, unless it's in a quoted segment:

```
keywords = 'pop rock "hard rock"';
keywords = keywords.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g);
console.log(keywords); // [pop, rock, "hard rock"]
```

However, I also want it to be possible to have quotes in keywords, like this:

```
keywords = 'pop rock "hard rock" "\"dream\" pop"';
```

This should return

```
[pop, rock, "hard rock", "\"dream\" pop"]
```

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can change your regex to:

```
keywords = keywords.match(/\w+|"(?:\\"|[^"])+"/g);
```

Instead of `[^"]+` you've got `(?:\\"|[^"])+` which allows `\"` or other character, but not an unescaped quote.

One important note is that if you want the string to include a literal slash, it should be:

```
keywords = 'pop rock "hard rock" "\\"dream\\" pop"'; //note the escaped slashes.
```

Also, there's a slight inconsistency between `\w+` and `[^"]+` - for example, it will match the word `"ab*d"`, but not `ab*d` (without quotes). Consider using `[^"\s]+` instead, that will match non-spaces.

Comment: I suggest you use `\\.` instead of `\\"` because backslashes can be escaped too, and you wouldn't want to miss `"foo\\\\"`.

Comment: @Tim - interesting idea at first, but I'm not sure it's necessary - wouldn't `[^"]` handle these cases? Am I missing something?

Comment: Consider this: In the string `"\\" "foo"` (just two backlashes for clarity), the first `"` would be matched by the literal `"` at the start of the regex. Then the `[^"]` would match the first \. Then the remaining `\"` would be matched by `\\"` (because it comes first in the alternation). Then `[^"]` would match the space and the `"` (at the end of the regex) would match the opening quote of `"foo"`, disrupting the parsing.

Comment: It works just like it should. "(?:\\"|[^"])+ which should be self-explanatory" < not really ;-), I never used this in regexps before, a colleague had to explain it to me. "Consider using [^"\s]+ instead" < This is something I already adjusted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tim - That would be the same for `"A\" "foo"` - the second quote is escaped, which fits the requirements here, but I get your point - it's a good idea not to allow lonely slashes, something like `\w+|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])+"`.

Comment: @Blaise - no problem. It a small leap from `[^"]` to `\\"|[^"]`, but then you need a group, and you might as well make it a non-capturing group... I guess I took too many steps at once `:P`

Comment: @Kobi: It would not be the same for `"A\" "foo"` - in `"\\" "foo"` the second quote is *not* escaped.

Comment: Can someone please explain the self-explanatory bit?

Comment: Very nice. It seems that one problem remains: `\"a b c"` is considered to be within quotes, because the leading escape is ignored.

Comment: @Timo - That is correct. I think for the purpose of this question `\"` is only considered valid within quotes, like in programming languages.

Comment: @Kobi Fair point. For whom it concerns, I have prepended `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*` to the regex. That is, *not* preceded by a backslash, and then there must be an even number of backslashes (i.e. escaped backslashes). In other words, the opening quote must be preceded by 0, 2, 4, 6, ... backslashes, or else (i.e. 1, 3, ... backslashes) we will not consider it to be an opening quote.

Comment: @Timo: unfortunately this approach is wrong, since the lookbehind doesn't exist in javascript, and even if it is possible, it isn't efficient at all. See my answer for example.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Right, I forgot. It is inefficient because the lookbehind will walk back to the start of the text to count the backslashes? It does not think to execute this part as it walks forward through the text initially?

Comment: In JavaScript, if you don't want the quotes too, you can just use `keywords = keywords.match(/\w+|"(?:\\"|[^"])+"/g).map((a) -> if a.match(/".+"/g) then a.slice(1, -1) else a)`. Not pure regex, but still doesn't require a feature JavaScript still doesn't have: regex look-behinds.

Comment: @Gustavo6046 - You probably meant `? :`. I don't think JavaScript has `then`.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot to _decaffeinate_ the code :P  Thank you.

Comment: An explanation of how this regex works, like @CasimiretHippolyte does in their answer, would be nice. It's also worth noting that this seems to split the string by any non-alpha-numeric characters, eg. `C.S.` -> `["C", "S"]`.

Comment: this doesnt support a quote preceded by a scaped scape

Answer (score 11):

ES6 solution supporting:

- Split by space except for inside quotes
- Removing quotes but not for backslash escaped quotes
- Escaped quote become quote
- Can put quotes anywhere

Code:

```
keywords.match(/\\?.|^$/g).reduce((p, c) => {
        if(c === '"'){
            p.quote ^= 1;
        }else if(!p.quote && c === ' '){
            p.a.push('');
        }else{
            p.a[p.a.length-1] += c.replace(/\\(.)/,"$1");
        }
        return  p;
    }, {a: ['']}).a
```

Output:

```
[ 'pop', 'rock', 'hard rock', '"dream" pop' ]
```

Comment: Your code is really hard to read but it works and is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: this works and TRIMS QUOTES which is what I needed; agree it is hard to read though

Comment: This regex eats newlines (`\n`), but it can be easily fixed by adding the `s` modifier (`/\\?.|^$/gs`).

Answer (score 4):

If Kobi's answer works well for the example string, it doesn't when there are more than one successive escape characters *(backslashes)* between quotes as Tim Pietzcker noticed it in comments. To handle these cases, the pattern can be written like this *(for the match method)*:

```
(?=\S)[^"\s]*(?:"[^\\"]*(?:\\[\s\S][^\\"]*)*"[^"\s]*)*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/SzzJDE/1)

Where `(?=\S)` ensures there's at least one non-white-space character at the current position since the following, that describes all allowed sub-strings *(including whitespaces between quotes)* is totally optional.

Details:

```
(?=\S)   # followed by a non-whitespace
[^"\s]*  #"# zero or more characters that aren't a quote or a whitespace
(?: # when a quoted substring occurs:
    "       #"# opening quote
    [^\\"]* #"# zero or more characters that aren't a quote or a backslash
    (?: # when a backslash is encountered:
        \\ [\s\S] # an escaped character (including a quote or a backslash)
        [^\\"]* #"#
    )*
    "         #"# closing quote
    [^"\s]*   #"#
)*
```

Comment: Could you add the intention of each part in plain English?

Comment: @Timo: I added the pattern details.

Comment: this works and PRESERVES QUOTES as I believe the OP was asking for.

Comment: this works great! but what if i want to make it work for single quotes as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out I had the same regex as you,

```
/\w+|"[^"]+"/g
```

but it didnt worked on empty quoted string such as :

```
"" "hello" "" "hi"
```

so I had to change the + quantifier by *.
this gave me :

```
str.match(/\w+|"[^"]*"/g);
```

Which is fine.

(ex: https://regex101.com/r/wm5puK/1)