# How do I split a string by space in javascript, except when the spaces occur between "quote"?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, string, split

Ultimately I'm trying to turn this:

```
var msg = '-m "this is a message" --echo "another message" test arg';
```

into this:

```
[
    '-m',
    'this is a message',
    '--echo',
    'another message',
    'test',
    'arg'
]
```

I'm not quite sure how to parse the string to get the desired results. This is what I have so far:

```
var msg = '-m "this is a message" --echo "another message" test arg';

// remove spaces from all quoted strings.
msg = msg.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function (match) {
    return match.replace(/ /g, '{space}');
});

// Now turn it into an array.
var msgArray = msg.split(' ').forEach(function (item) {
    item = item.replace('{space}', ' ');
});
```

I think that will work, but man does that seem like a fickle and backwards way of accomplishing what I want. I'm sure you guys have a much better way than creating a placeholder string before the split.

Comment: Having nested quotes with regex might not be the best option, recursion is not very friendly with regex.

Comment: You could split by quotes, then split every alternate item.

Comment: I'm not allowing nested quotes, that's why I exclude matches with quotes in the middle `[^"]*`, otherwise that expression would match the entire string between the first and last quote.

Comment: I m surprised to see that the question this one is marked as duplicate of does not have an answer. So, is it a duplicate ?

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't consider my question a duplicate of the one linked, but oh well.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of the linked question, as this is javascript and the other is java. However, it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031900/split-a-string-by-whitespace-keeping-quoted-segments-allowing-escaped-quotes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261635/javascript-split-string-by-space-but-ignore-space-in-quotes-notice-not-to-spli

Comment: It's also over two years old, lol. And your second link was posted *after* this question, making it the duplicate in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with exec(), you can allready take the strings without the quotes :

```
var test="once \"upon a time\"  there was   a  \"monster\" blue";

function parseString(str) {
    var re = /(?:")([^"]+)(?:")|([^\s"]+)(?=\s+|$)/g;
    var res=[], arr=null;
    while (arr = re.exec(str)) { res.push(arr[1] ? arr[1] : arr[0]); }
    return res;
}

var parseRes= parseString(test);
// parseRes now contains what you seek
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was wondering if there was a better way to get the quoted values without the quotes, but didn't want to be pedantic and drag this question out. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a `split`, you could `match`:

```
var msg = '-m "this is a message" --echo "another message" test arg';
var array = msg.match(/"[^"]*"|[^\s"]+/g);
console.log(array);
```

produces:

```
[ '-m',
  '"this is a message"',
  '--echo',
  '"another message"',
  'test',
  'arg' ]
```

Comment: Much simpler. Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to filter the double quotes from the final array, since they aren't present in the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess what you would prefer as a solution, but one approach would be to split by quotes (this assumes no nested quotes), then to split every alternate item by spaces:

```
result = [];
msg.split("\"").map(function(v, i ,a){
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        result = result.concat(v.split(" ").filter(function(v){
            return !v;
        }));
    } else {
        result.push(v);
    }
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/eL7cc/

Comment: This is at least better than using a placeholder string :)