# javascript split string by space, but ignore space in quotes (notice not to split by the colon too)

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need help splitting a string in javascript by space (" "), ignoring space inside quotes expression.

I have this string:

```
var str = 'Time:"Last 7 Days" Time:"Last 30 Days"';
```

I would expect my string to be split to 2:

```
['Time:"Last 7 Days"', 'Time:"Last 30 Days"']
```

but my code splits to 4:

```
['Time:', '"Last 7 Days"', 'Time:', '"Last 30 Days"']
```

this is my code:

```
str.match(/(".*?"|[^"\s]+)(?=\s*|\s*$)/g);
```

Thanks!

Comment: While the linked question is _related_, it is _not_ a duplicate: _This_ question explicitly wants unquoted strings that directly adjoin double-quoted strings  (e.g., `foo:"bar none"`) to be recognized as a _single_ token (and also doesn't mention the need to handle escaped double-quotes.)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
s = 'Time:"Last 7 Days" Time:"Last 30 Days"'
s.match(/(?:[^\s"]+|"[^"]*")+/g) 

// -> ['Time:"Last 7 Days"', 'Time:"Last 30 Days"']
```

Explained:

```
(?:         # non-capturing group
  [^\s"]+   # anything that's not a space or a double-quote
  |         #   or…
  "         # opening double-quote
    [^"]*   # …followed by zero or more chacacters that are not a double-quote
  "         # …closing double-quote
)+          # each match is one or more of the things described in the group
```

Turns out, to fix your original expression, you just need to add a `+` on the group:

```
str.match(/(".*?"|[^"\s]+)+(?=\s*|\s*$)/g)
#                         ^ here.
```

Comment: This would be a good answer if you explained the regular expression.

Comment: just getting it out there first.

Comment: is there a way to exclude the double quotes by adjusting the regex? i.e. output `['Time:Last 7 Days', 'Time:Last 30 Days']`

Comment: @Awalias not with just using the `match` method. But if you `replace` afterwards, you can use capture groups etc and leave the quotes out. Probably better for you to post a new question.

Comment: Is there a way to handle spaces after colon too. e.g var str = 'Time: "Last 7 Days" Time: "Last 30 Days"'; => ['Time: "Last 7 Days"', 'Time: "Last 30 Days"']

Comment: Modified version of kch's pattern that works with single or double quotes: `s.match(/(?:[^\s"']+|['"][^'"]*["'])+/g) `

Comment: What if the quotes are escaped, without using negative lookaheads (due to compatibility)?

Comment: Not sure if this is just a false positive or not, but this snippet was flagged as "Inefficient regular expression: This part of the regular expression may cause exponential backtracking on strings
containing many repetitions of '!'." by CodeQL on GitHub. Issue about it is here: https://github.com/github/codeql/issues/5964

Answer (score 7):

ES6 solution supporting:

- Split by space except for inside quotes
- Removing quotes but not for backslash escaped quotes
- Escaped quote become quote

Code:

```
str.match(/\\?.|^$/g).reduce((p, c) => {
        if(c === '"'){
            p.quote ^= 1;
        }else if(!p.quote && c === ' '){
            p.a.push('');
        }else{
            p.a[p.a.length-1] += c.replace(/\\(.)/,"$1");
        }
        return  p;
    }, {a: ['']}).a
```

Output:

```
[ 'Time:Last 7 Days', 'Time:Last 30 Days' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This Works for me..

var myString = 'foo bar "sdkgyu sdkjbh zkdjv" baz "qux quux" skduy "zsk"';
console.log(myString.split(/([^\s"]+|"[^"]*")+/g));

**Output:**
Array ["", "foo", " ", "bar", " ", ""sdkgyu sdkjbh zkdjv"", " ", "baz", " ", ""qux quux"", " ", "skduy", " ", ""zsk"", ""]

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is about regex, but the more tasks like string splitting or substrings extracting you do with regex the more you notice that complexity of your regular expressions grow **much** quicker than complexity of your strings: first you have to avoid splitting by delimiter if it is in quoted zone, you just use some almost random regex that somehow works; then you need to respect double quoted zones, you modify your regex so it grows 3-4 times; and so on. Eventually your regex turns into such a wunschpunsch that no sober person will ever want to support the thing. So, although regex solutions first look very ninja and [elegant](https://media.tenor.com/9PWLGDM1WsAAAAAd/elegance-spy-x-family.gif), I finally stopped using it and switched to custom function that respects quoted zones:

```
interface IZoneToken {
  begin: string;
  end: string;
}

const ZONE_TOKENS: { [key: string]: IZoneToken } = {
  SINGLE_QUOTES: { begin: '\'', end: '\'' },
  DOUBLE_QUOTES: { begin: '\"', end: '\"' },
  ROUND_BRACKETS: { begin: '(' , end: ')' }
};

function splitRespectingZones(input: string, delimiter: string, zone_tokens: IZoneToken[]): string[] {
  let current_substring = '',
    current_zone_token;
  const substrings = [],
    current_zone_tokens = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    const symbol = input[i];

    if (symbol === delimiter && !current_zone_tokens.length) {
      substrings.push(current_substring);
      current_substring = '';
    } else {
      if (current_zone_token = zone_tokens.find(x => symbol === x.begin || symbol === x.end)) {
        if (current_zone_token === current_zone_tokens.last()) {
          if (current_zone_token.end === symbol) {
            current_zone_tokens.pop()
          } else {
            current_zone_tokens.push(current_zone_token)
          }
        } else {
          current_zone_tokens.push(current_zone_token)
        }
        current_zone_token = undefined;
      }
      current_substring += symbol;
    }
  }
  if (current_substring) {
    substrings.push(current_substring)
  }
  return substrings;
}
```

As you see, you can use any amount of custom zone tokens, be it double quotes, curly brackets or some other brackets:

```
splitRespectingZones(`some 'ran dom' "str ings" (fo r) ("example")`, ' ', [
  { begin: '\'', end: '\'' },
  { begin: '\"', end: '\"' },
  { begin: '(' , end: ')' }
])

// ['some', "'ran dom'", '"str ings"', '(fo r)', '("example")']
```

This is verbose, but if you ever need to modify this function you'll love how straightforward its logic is

Example for case from the question:

```
splitRespectingZones('Time:"Last 7 Days" Time:"Last 30 Days"', ' ', [ { begin: '\"', end: '\"' } ])
// ['Time:"Last 7 Days"', 'Time:"Last 30 Days"']
```