# Javascript split by spaces, but not within html-tags

Tags: javascript, regex, split

My first goal is to split a string by spaces, but not the ones within html-tags.

I've tried to rewrite the following, unsuccessfully: [Javascript split by spaces but not those in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663683/javascript-split-by-spaces-but-not-those-in-quotes)

What would the regex look like in:
arr = fullHtmlString.split(**?**);
?

---

My main goal is to shift an IMG-tag by one space at a time.
After that I'll iterate over the array, search for the img-tag, remove it, and add it the next item, and finally join the array.

The code I use at the moment is quite comprehensive and use jQuery extensively to achive the goal.

Input:

```
<div>
    <p><img class=something>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
</div>
```

Deisred output first time:

```
<div>
    <p>Some<img class=something> text.</p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
</div>
```

...second time:

```
<div>
    <p>Some text.<img class=something></p>
    <p>Some more text.</p>
</div>
```

...third time:

```
<div>
    <p>Some text.</p>
    <p><img class=something>Some more text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give you give an example of your input followed by desired output?

Comment: provide a fiddle please\

Comment: Sounds like DOM manipulation with regular expressions, which isn't a good thing ?

Comment: Try passing the string into a `DOMParser`

Comment: `htmlstring.match(/(\<[\S\s]*?\>)/g);` is a rough way of doing it

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this leaves me without the text-nodes. I need to be able to join the array and not loose any of the data. 

Original post updated with input and desired output.

Comment: @ErlendJones: Please check out a series of demos on https://regex101.com/r/iK7mW9/1 - all up to https://regex101.com/r/iK7mW9/7. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to do this with a regular expression, [why explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/560593).

You can use DOM properties and methods though

```js
function run(){
  var img  = document.querySelector(".something"),
   sibling = img,
   parent  = img.parentNode,
   next    = parent.nextElementSibling;

  //Search for the next textNode
  while((sibling = sibling.nextSibling) && sibling.nodeType !=3);

  if(sibling) {
    //split the text only once, 
    //so "some more text" becomes ["some","more text"]
    var textParts = sibling.textContent.split(/ (.*)?/,2);

    //put the first split item before the sibling
    parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(textParts[0]+" "),sibling);

    //replace the sibling with the img element
    parent.replaceChild(img,sibling);

    //finally if there was more text insert it after the img
    textParts[1] && parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(textParts[1]),img.nextSibling);    
  } else if(!sibling && next) {
    //no sibling in the current parent, 
    //so prepend it to the next available element in parent
    next.insertBefore(img,next.firstChild);
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}

var timer = setInterval(run,2000);
```

```html
<div>
    <p><img class="something" src="http://placehold.it/10x10">Some text.</p>
    <p>Some <span>skip me</span> more text.</p>
</div>
```