# Regex to seperate strings by html tags and and spaces in normal string

Tags: javascript, java, regex, jsoup

Spent alot of time on this. This is my current state of codes

```
var str = '<div class="x"><p>this is <span> example </span>text</p></div>';
var arr = str.split(/\s*(<[^>]*>)/g );
arr = arr.filter(function(n){ return n != '' }); 
alert(arr);
```

Not a regex fan but struggled to achieve the out put

```
["<div class="x">", "<p>", "this is", "<span>", " example", "</span>", "text", "</p>", "</div>"]
```

What my expectation is

```
["<div class="x">", "<p>", "this", "is", "<span>", " example", "</span>", "text", "</p>", "</div>"]
```

The difference is expected and current is very minor. All I need is if any string have multiple terms they also need to be get as separated strings, if that doesn't contain any html tags on a whole.

Look at the difference at third element. I would like to achieve in the same regex if possible. Otherwise it is okay to do some processing later on.

[**Play Ground**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/uraLznfm/).

Note : I am using Jsoup in the back end for further processing. Any Jsoup/Java solution also would be fine

Comment: Don't use regex on html. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5054380 at 71k rep, I'm sure you know better.

Comment: Is the whitespace in `" example"` important or could/should it be removed?

Comment: @BaldBantha I read that post and it is not a full document at all. It just a single line of string always.

Comment: @Rawing It is not important. We can remove that.

Comment: if the element does not contain `<` or `>` then split by space.... that simple?

Comment: `match` [`(<[^>]*>|\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vT4mD8/1)

Comment: @BaldBantha I KNOW THAT. It contains.

Comment: @Tushar Thanks Tushar for that solution. However, when I placed regex in fiddle, syntax error ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261635/javascript-split-string-by-space-but-ignore-space-in-quotes-notice-not-to-spli this is split except space in quotes but it can probably be adapted for space in `<` and `>`.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes Tunaki. Trying it right away. Noob in regex :D

Comment: [`console.log('<div class="x"><p>this is <span> example </span>text</p></div>'.match(/(<[^>]*>|\w+)/g))`](https://fiddle.jshell.net/j5wz0rug/)

Comment: _"Regex to seperate strings by space within html string"_ No space character appears between `<div>` and `<p>` at `<div class="x"><p>`?

Comment: @guest271314 You are correct. Wording is wrong. I'll fix it now. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @Tushar Please add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var str = '<div class="x"><p>this is <span> example </span>text</p></div>';
var arr = str.split(/\s*(<[^>]*>)/g );
arr = arr.filter(function(n){ return n !== ''; });
var c = [];
for(var i =0; i <arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i].includes("<")){
    c.push(arr[i]);
  }
  else{
   var u = arr[i].split(" ");
    for(var j = 0; j < u.length; j++){
      c.push(u[j]);
    }
  }
}
c = c.filter(function(n){ return n !== ''; });
console.log(c);
alert(c);
```

Comment: Ahh. .Thanks for the effort.Really appreciate it. But the regex solution is working great. Will get back to this once it is breaking in production :D

Comment: I was bored. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```js
var re = /<[^>]+>|\w+/g; 
var str = '<div class="x"><p>this is <span> example </span>text</p></div>';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
document.getElementById('console').value+=m[0]+'\n';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="console" cols="40" rows="15">
</textarea>
```