# How to delete line in multiline string?

Tags: javascript, string, special-characters

I have a multiline stock. How can I remove a specific line?

```
const str = `
  import 'C:\Users\Desktop\sanitize.js';
  val = ln + '\t';
  val += lc + '\t';
  val += f + '\t'; 
  val += id + '\t'; // id source
  val += sc + '\t\n';
`;
```

In this case, I need to delete lines where Import or reguired occurs, while maintaining line breaks.

My approach doesn't work, because there can be a line break inside the lines, and I'm trying to split the line by line breaks in order to achieve the result.

```
function sanitizeSandbox(code) {
  let disinfectedSandbox = '';

  if (typeof code === 'string' && code.length > 0) {
    const sandboxSplit = code.split('\n');
    
    for (const str of sandboxSplit) {
      if (!str.includes('import') && !str.includes('required')) {
        disinfectedSandbox += `${str}\n`;
      }
    }
  }

  return disinfectedSandbox;
}
```

Expected value:

```
`
 val = ln + '\t';
 val += lc + '\t';
 val += f + '\t'; 
 val += id + '\t'; // id source
 val += sc + '\t\n';
`
```

The value I get with my approach:

```
`
 val = ln + '\t';
 val += lc + '\t';
 val += f + '\t';
 val += id + '\t'; // id source
 val += sc + '\t
 \n';
`
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: @Nick described above

Comment: Surely your input would be `\\t` and `\\n`, so that the actual string when used contains `\t` and `\n`...? Right now you have active escape codes in your string, so it will be `val = ln + 'AN ACTUAL TAB HERE';` etc. (having said that, why is your input a series of string concatenations at all, instead of an array join on tab with an implied newline or the like?)

Comment: Do all the lines always end with a `;`?

Comment: @ArleighHix no, not always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex (derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261693/9473764)):

```
(?:[^\n']|'[^']*')+
```

to match lines in your string (while ignoring newlines within `''`), then filter based on whether or not the line contains `import` or `required`:

```js
const str = `
  import 'C:\Users\Desktop\sanitize.js';
  val = ln + '\t';
  val += lc + '\t';
  val += f + '\t'; 
  val += id + '\t'; // id source
  val += sc + '\t\n';
`;

result = str.match(/(?:[^\n']|'[^']*')+/g)
  .filter(l => !l.match(/\b(import|require)\b/))
  .join('\n')
  
console.log(result)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow ignore special characters when working with strings? Now, when executing, instead of \t, a space is put, and instead of \n, a line break. Is it possible to leave special characters in their places and not execute them?

Comment: @Vladislav I'm not sure exactly what you mean. This code is independent of what is in the lines, it only cares about the newlines at the end.

Comment: there is a newline on the fifth line which I would like to ignore

Comment: please look again at the value that I expect

Comment: @Vladislav take a look at the output of my code, the newline is present in the output string. It just shows up as a newline when logged to the console. Take a look at my edit, I'm outputting the JSON encoded string as well and you can see the newline present as expected.

Comment: thanks a lot i was able to figure it out

Comment: @Vladislav OK. great, I'm glad I could help