# javascript using regex to get multiple separates including text string separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that I wish to split using multiple separators (including a string separator which I can't find much information on)

I wish to split the string on occurrences of / and the string AGL but that the moment when I print out the array array[0] I just get L. Quotes around the string AGL don't seem to make a difference.

```
str = "LLF ABC TEMP / HERE / RET / UP TP 12F AGL PLACENAME VALUES / AVM / ABC / PPP / END"
var array = [];
array = str.split(/(AGL|\/|)/g);
```

So at the end my array should have 9 items.

LLF ABC TEMP

HERE

RET

UP TP 12F

PLACENAME VALUES

AVM

ABC

PPP

END

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a function that will do it [without the use of regex"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32754249/1533592)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
str = "LLF ABC TEMP / HERE / RET / UP TP 12F AGL PLACENAME VALUES / AVM / ABC / PPP / END"
var array = str.split(/\s*(?:AGL|\/)\s*/);
console.log(array);
```

Note you do not need `/g` flag with `.split`, it is the default behavior.

The `\s*(?:AGL|\/)\s*` regex matches

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:AGL|\/)` - a non-capturing group (so that its value could not land in the resulting array) matching either `AGL` or `/`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were trying to do, was a little tricky, since you need to use the lookbehind group:

```js
str = "LLF ABC TEMP / HERE / RET / UP TP 12F AGL PLACENAME VALUES / AVM / ABC / PPP / END"
var array = [];
array = str.match(/(\b(AGL)|(\w+([^\/])(?!(AGL)))+\b)/g); 
console.log(array)
```

This is the regex (/(\b(AGL)|(\w+([^/])(?!(AGL)))+\b)/g).
I also used match instead of split, so you don't get Undefined, empty string values and '/' values in your array.

If this isn't exactly what you were looking for, see:
regexr.com/66jhd
It's a great little web tool for testing regex.