# Javascript seperate with regex but take like one word if string surround by specific chars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split

```
var mystring = 'Hello test1 "test2 but one word" test3 test4  '; 

var mystring_ar= mystring.split(/\s+/);
```

okay I have this `/\s+/` expression so I can seperate from spaces but my problem is I want to seperate from spaces and regular expression should not seperate word if words surrounded by `"`, like `"test2 but one word"` For example below:

```
'Hello test1 "test2 but one word" test3 test4  '.split(regex) 
=> ['Hello','test1','test2 but one word','test3','test4']
```

is that possible?

**Edited**
I have found half solution but not completed below code seperate correctly but only works for words for example if string is `a/b/as d` , it will not seperate it to `a/b/as and d`,it will seperate it to `a,b,as,d`

`keywords = keywords.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g);`

But  I think solution should be with `split`.It should work like seperate from `whitespaces` and don't seperate inside of `""`

Comment: Related: [Split a string by whitespace, keeping quoted segments, allowing escaped quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031900/split-a-string-by-whitespace-keeping-quoted-segments-allowing-escaped-quotes)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thank you it solved my problem :)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski but I got problem with solution that I have found in link .It uses ` /\w+|"[^"]+"/g ` but it only accept words, but I need seperate from whitespaces but if it is between `"asd asd asd"` It should not seperate them.But it seems like `/\w+|"[^"]+"/g ` this expression also seperate `t1/t2 to t1 and t2 which is not correct for this problem`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I think solution should be with split.It should work like seperate from whitespaces and don't seperate inside of "".How can I do that?

Comment: Then use `\S` instead of `\w`, and put the quoted expression first: `/"[^"]*"|\S+/g` (with `match`).

Comment: @trincot thank you it worked  like a charm :)

Comment: OK, I've put that as an answer with a little optional addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works easier with `match`. To match any non-white-space, you can use the opposite of `\s`, i.e. `\S`. As quotes also match with `\S`, you then also need to first test for the quote, and only put the `\S` as alternative of that. Maybe you also want to ignore a quoted part, when it is followed immediately by a non-space, like `"thi"s word"` should maybe not become `['thi','s','word']`, but`['"thi"s','word']`. That you can do with negative look ahead: `(?!\S)`. All together that becomes:

```
/"[^"]*"(?!\S)|\S+/g
```