# How can I get a substring located between 2 quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string that looks like this: "the word you need is 'hello' ".

What's the best way to put 'hello' (but without the quotes) into a javascript variable? I imagine that the way to do this is with regex (which I know very little about) ?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Could the quoted string also contain escaped quotes? (`"He said: 'Hello, O\'Brian.'"`)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
> var s =  "the word you need is 'hello' ";
> s.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1];
"hello"
```

This will match a starting `'`, followed by anything except `'`, and then the closing `'`, storing everything in between in the *first* captured group.

Comment: You don't have to check for a character except `'` because you filter up to the next `'` anyway. So `s.match(/'(\w*)'/)[1]` suffices, or `/'(\w+)'/` if it has to be at least one character (I assumed you could also have `"the word you need is ''"`).

Comment: @Simon: Because group `0` holds the entire matched text. Thus, with `/'\w*'/`, you'd get `'hello'` instead of just `hello`.

Comment: @JoãoSilva, how do I get just `hello` not `'hello'`?

Comment: how to get only the value if there are multiple quotation mark occurred?

Comment: How would you get multiple occurrences of strings in quotes? Say you want to get 'hello' as well as 'goodbye' from the following string: "the word you need is 'hello' not 'goodbye'".

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Bbh6P/

```
var mystring = "the word you need is 'hello'"
var matches = mystring.match(/\'(.*?)\'/);  //returns array

​alert(matches[1]);​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid regular expressions then you can use `.split("'")` to split the string at single quotes , then use `jquery.map()` to return just the odd indexed substrings, ie. an array of all single-quoted substrings.

```
var str = "the word you need is 'hello'";
var singleQuoted = $.map(str.split("'"), function(substr, i) {
   return (i % 2) ? substr : null;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GwCUc/1/)**

### CAUTION

**This and other methods will get it wrong if one or more apostrophes (same as single quote) appear in the original string.**