# JavaScript IDE?

Tags: javascript, python, macos

This is a super basic question I am just unfamiliar with the definitions to some of the terminology. I am using a mac and i'm looking for a IDE(I assume it is an IDE as that is what I use for python) so I can write in JavaScript for study offline and see my results. I have searched google, downloaded Aptana Studio 3 and a few other suggestions, also I have the latest version of Xcode. Maybe I am just overthinking this or it is my lack of experience but I can not seem to figure  out how to write JavaScript or other specific languages inside one IDE. Sorry if this seems like too straight forward to answer but i'd really like to find an IDE for OSX that is free, writes at least html5, css, and JavaScript. Yes, I have googled that and how to begin writing JavaScript on a mac. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132593/simple-javascript-ide

Comment: it depends...do you prefer free IDE or are you ready to buy an editor..There is specially designed ide by jet brains for javascript.But my bet is on sublime text2.There is an avalanche of coders shifting their editors to use sublime..the best of all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an IDE stands for Integrated Development Enviroment so a program that helps you write programs is an IDE

an IDE for javascript could be any text editor, write your code as regular text save it with .js as extension and add a reference to that file from an html page.

I think you can use these free IDE's on mac:

Sublime Text and 
Aptana Studio

I'm sure there's alot more, just google it

Comment: Thanks, I over complicated that a lot. Just needed your second sentence.

Comment: While just about any text editor would suffice, what most provide would be much less than the facilities offered by most IDEs for code development.