# How to concatenate variable names in objects

Tags: javascript

I am checking a value from an input text a form, the name of the input is

```
name="name['title']"
```

title, doing something like this:

```
if (!values.title) {
    errors.title = 'Required';
}
```

I have to do this for some other controls, so I thought I could make the control name dynamic, how can I achieve something like this?

```
let name = 'title';
if (!values.<name>) {
    errors.<name> = 'Required';
}
```

I updated the question to show how it is different from proposed solutions.

Comment: `values[name]` and `errors[name]` will do the trick

Comment: thanks Federico your answer is correct however I made a mistake and I updated the question, the name of the control is slightly different.

Comment: You can extract "title" from `name` (I think that's what you're asking) [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367126/how-can-i-get-a-substring-located-between-2-quotes)