# Is there a way to make every word different color in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I wanted to make every word in the text different color, but I've only find code to make every letter in the text a different color. Is there any way to turn this to change color in every word instead every letter?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var message = "The quick brown fox.";
       var colors = new Array("#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"); // red, green, blue
       for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
          document.write("<span style=\"color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";\">" + message[i] + "</span>");
    </script>
```

Comment: Imho split the message by whitespace and loop the array.

Comment: Yes, the answer is to split the string into an array of words. See this also this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817646/javascript-split-string-on-space-or-on-quotes-to-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small change required.

Split the message into an array by space (`" "`)

```
   var message = "The quick brown fox.";
   var messageArr = message.split(" ");
   var colors = ["#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"]; // red, green, blue
   for (var i = 0; i < messageArr .length; i++)
   {
      document.write("<span style='color:" + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ";'>" + messageArr[i] + " </span>");
   }
```

See it on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAHNT/)

**Note:** I've also changed your `colors` array definition to using the array literal notation `[]`, which is a slightly better way of declaring an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = "The quick brown fox.",
    words   = message.split(/\s+/),
    colors  = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'];

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    document.write('<span style="color: ' + colors[(i % colors.length)] + ';">' + words[i] + '</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "Glee is very very awesome!";
text = text.split(" ");
var colors = ["red", "green", "rgb(0, 162, 232)"]; //you can use color names, as well as RGB notation
var n = colors.length; //no need to re-grab length each time
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i ++) {
    document.write('<span style = "color: ' + colors[i % n] + '">' + text[i] + '</span>');
}
```

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/7hGVs/).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try some different way. ***[The live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Paj7E/)***

```
var message = "The quick brown fox.",
    colors = ["#ff0000","#00ff00","#0000ff"],
    i = 0, len = colors.length;

message = message.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, function (match, word) {
    return '<span style="color: ' + colors[(i++ % len)] + ';">' + word + '</span>';
});
document.write(message);
​
```