# Iterate over set elements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have turned on the Chrome flag for experimental ECMAscript 6 features, one of which is `Set`. As I understand, the details of `Set` are broadly agreed upon by the spec writers.

I create a set `a` and add the string `'Hello'`

```
a = Set();
a.add('Hello');
```

but how do I iterate over the elements of `a`?

```
for(let i of a) { console.log(i); }
```

gives "SyntaxError: Illegal `let` declaration outside extended mode"

```
for(var i of a) { console.log(i); }
```

gives "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

```
for(var i in a) { console.log(i); }
```

gives `Undefined`

Is it possible to iterate over of a set in Chrome 26?

Comment: [Looks like for-of](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6) is only supported in Firefox currently...

Comment: [How to implement a Set in JavaScript](http://www.javascriptexamples.org/2011/01/17/how-to-implement-a-set-in-javascript/)

Comment: can you use this: http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/set.html

Comment: See [Browser compatibility for `Set.prototype[@@iterator]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator#browser_compatibility) in the MDN docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `of` operator [doesn't appear to be currently supported in Chrome](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/). It seems that only FireFox versions 13 through 18 support it. It also appears that none of the browsers actually support `Set` although the page does say that some of the tests represent existence and not full functionality or coherence. So it might be that `Set` is partially implemented in Chrome.

Comment: Tested in 2020; for-of works for me in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: ...BUT I had trouble with it in webpack/node.

Answer (score 83):

A very easy way is to turn the Set into an Array first:

```
let a = new Set();
a.add('Hello');
a = Array.from(a);
```

...and then just use a simple for loop.

Be aware that `Array.from` is not supported in IE11.

Comment: Also, it has a second, optional parameter which is a mapping function to call on every element, i.e: `a = Array.from(a, e => e.length)`.

Answer (score 54):

There are two methods you can use.
**for...of**
and  **forEach**

```
let a = new Set();
a.add('Hello');

for(let key of a) console.log(key)

a.forEach(key => console.log(key))
```

Answer (score 39):

Upon the spec from MDN, `Set` has a [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) method:

> The values() method returns a new Iterator object that contains the values for each element in the Set object in insertion order.

So, for iterate through the values, I would do:

```
var s = new Set(['a1', 'a2'])
for (var it = s.values(), val= null; val=it.next().value; ) {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: When the iteration would be stopped then? According to the docs, StopIteration would be thrown. Using an exception for stopping the iteration is an awful solution.

Comment: If you are referring to MDN doc about Iterator, I am not sure if their doc is still accurate, they also has a Warning on the page. The iterator will stop advancing once it reaches the end.

Comment: althought it worked for me, i didn't get why the for loop has only 2 statements, like why its' not '''var it = s.values(), val= null; ; val=it.next().value'''

Answer (score 32):

I use the `forEach(..);` function. ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach))

Comment: I can't be cause I want to call 'await of an async function from my loop.

Comment: @Kris does `forEach(async () => await stuff())` not work?

Comment: This question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop explains it better than I could. But basically, foreach will work in a sense, but not how you expect it to. The foreach will not wait and execute your blocks of code sequentially. It fires them of in parallel. Maybe that could be what you want, but its not really equivalent to a for loop.

Comment: For Asynchronous code use Promise.all(loop here)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the spread operator to convert a `Set` into an array (an alternative to `Array.from(yourSet)`).

```js
const mySet = new Set();

mySet.add('a');
mySet.add('b')

const iterableSet = [...mySet];
// end up with: ['a', 'b']

// use any Array method on `iterableSet`
const lettersPlusSomething = iterableSet.map(letter => letter + ' something');
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple functional approach is to just use `forEach`

```js
const mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3])
mySet.forEach(a => { console.log(a) })
// 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 5):

Even if the syntactic sugar for iteration hasn't been implemented yet, you can probably still use iterators.

http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/for-of-ff13.html explains

> The special method `__iterator__` returns an iterator object. Such an object has a method `next()` that either returns the next element in the current iteration sequence or throws `StopIteration` if there are no more elements.

So you should be able to iterate over the set using

```
for (var it = mySet.__iterator__();;) {
  var element;
  try {
    element = it.next();
  } catch (ex) {
    if (ex instanceof StopIteration) {
      break;
    } else {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
  // Do something with element
}
```

You can also define a functional version of for…of like

```
function forOf(collection, f) {
  // jQuery.each calling convention for f.
  var applyToElement = f.bind(/* this */ collection, /* index */ void 0);
  for (var it = collection.__iterator__();;) {
    var element;
    try {
      element = it.next();
    } catch (ex) {
      if (ex instanceof StopIteration) {
        break;
      } else {
        throw ex;
      }
    }

    // jQuery.each return convention.
    if (applyToElement(element) === false) { break; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a little yucky, though.

Comment: @Randomblue, Yeah.  Syntactic sugar is meant to gloss over all that, but often different people implement the syntax support in the parser than implement the library code so you get releases with half of a feature.  When it's the syntax that lags you just have to desugar it yourself which requires seeing how sausage is made.

Comment: There is no such `__iterator__` method in the latest Node v0.11.4.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me

```js
mySet.forEach(async(item) =>{
   await doSomething(item)
 })
```

Comment: This will not work, async/await will not work within a forEach loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
let set = new Set();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);

// This will be an array now, now you can loop normally.
console.log([...set]);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This will create a new array our of set. Make sure you understand that before use.

Answer (score -1):

[@bizi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401216/iterate-over-set-elements#41653988) is close but it did not work for me. This worked on Firefox:

```
var s= new Set([1,2]),
     it = s.values();
 for (var val= it.next().value; val=it.next().value;) {
     console.log("set: "+val);
 }
```