# what is the fastest way to convert a string with words separated by ; into a set?

Tags: javascript, jsx

I have a string like "car;bus;airplane;bike"

what is the fastest way to convert it into a set in JavaScript JSX?

Is there something like:

```
"car;bus;airplane;bike".split(';').toSet()?
```

So the set will have  'car', 'bus', 'airplane', 'bike' as elements

Comment: new Set("car;bus;airplane;bike".split(';'))

Comment: Similar kind of question, since split converts string to array.

[javascript-array-to-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965112/javascript-array-to-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
let x = new Set("car;bus;airplane;bike".split(';'));
```

[Javscript Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) can be initialised as

```
new Set([iterable]);
```

you can initialise it with an [iterable object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterable)

Answer (score 1):

Use:
  new Set("car;bus;airplane;bike".split(';'))

Answer (score 1):

Since you can construct a `Set` from an itrerable, you could go for:

```
const theString = "car;bus;airplane;bike";
const theSet = new Set(theString.split(";"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Set` constructor:

```js
s = new Set("car;bus;airplane;bike".split(';'))
console.log(s.size);
console.log(s);
```

The constructor can take any iterable and convert the objects to be the set's elements.

> Note that stackoverflow's snippet will not show the log of `s` but if you use chrome you can open the console and find the relevant result there.

Answer (score 1):

You said "fastest" but all of the answers to date have used strings that they split into arrays and passed into the `Set` constructor. Cut out the middleman if you really meant "fastest":

```js
const s = new Set(["car","bus","airplane","bike"]);

console.log(s.size);
console.log(s.has("bus"));
```

Not that the speed of this operation is likely to be significant.

Answer (score -1):

const x = new Set('car;bus;bike'.split(';'));
console.log(x);