# Shallow-clone a Map or Set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do you shallow-clone a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object in JavaScript?

I want to get a new Map or Set that has the same keys and values.

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Use the constructor to clone Maps and Sets:

```
let clonedMap = new Map(originalMap);

let clonedSet = new Set(originalSet);
```

Comment: How to do a deep clone?

Comment: Check out this fiddle to see how to deep clone a map: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/5qtt2Len/1/

Comment: `Map` should be treated as an abstract data type, not as a Javascript object. Hence deep cloning a `Map` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately the copy constructor does not work in IE 11 (empty map is created).

Answer (score 16):

Shallow clone:

```
var clonedMap = new Map(originalMap)

var clonedSet = new Set(originalSet)
```

Deep clone:

```
var deepClonedMap = new Map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...originalMap])))
var deepClonedSet = new Set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...originalSet])))
```

```js
let originalMap = new Map()
let data = {a:'a',b:'b'}
originalMap.set(1,data)

let shallowCloned = new Map(originalMap)
let deepCloned = new Map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([...originalMap])))
data.a = 'p'
console.log('originalMap:',[...originalMap])
console.log('shallowCloned:',[...shallowCloned])
console.log('deepCloned:',[...deepCloned])
```

Comment: I guess it won't work if the `originalMap` has other maps/sets inside

Comment: Reminder: the parse/stringify method works ONLY with primitive values (strings, numbers, booleans). If you have BigInt, Date, Functions, etc. then it will BREAK.

Comment: For the deep clone, you should just do `structuredClone(originalMap)`

Answer (score 12):

Creating a new Set via a for loop is faster than the Set constructor. The same is true for Maps, although to a lesser degree.

```js
const timeInLoop = (desc, loopCount, fn) => {
  const d = `${desc}: ${loopCount.toExponential()}`
  console.time(d)
  for (let i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
    fn()
  }
  console.timeEnd(d)
}

const set = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

const setFromForLoop = x => {
  const y = new Set()
  for (const item of x) y.add(item)
  return y
}

const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5]])

const mapFromForLoop = x => {
  const y = new Map()
  for (const entry of x) y.set(...entry)
  return y
}

timeInLoop('new Set(set)', 1e5, () => new Set(set))

timeInLoop('setFromForLoop(set)', 1e5, () => setFromForLoop(set))

timeInLoop('new Map(map)', 1e5, () => new Map(map))

timeInLoop('mapFromForLoop(map)', 1e5, () => mapFromForLoop(map))
```

Comment: Nice find! It might be worth creating a bug on the Chromium bug tracker to call their attention to it. This is surely fixable in the engine. Similarly for Firefox, which exhibits the same issue for `Set` (though not for `Map`).

Comment: Interestingly, `new Set(set)` is about 15-20 ms faster in Safari, but `setFromForLoop(set)` is about 20-28 ms faster in Chrome.

Comment: This is interesting but dangerous info for young developers. Unless you absolutely MUST have the fastest possible times NOW, you are much better to use the constructor methods because as @JoLiss points out, this is a bug and will get fixed - it's someone else's problem, so the less code you can write the better!

Comment: Generally it's a really bad idea to worry about performance if you don't have a good reason to. Prioritize minimizing development time, or else there you end up being less efficient for no payoff.

Comment: super useful for folks that need performance for things like page load, albeit I don't see myself creating 10000 sets

Comment: @AntonOfTheWoods good point, but you could always just add a `cloneSet()` function which is documented with the reason to why this is used instead of the `Set` constructor, or simply a link to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This way has the smallest amount of code needed for shallow copying and does the job.

**Disclosure**: I did not test if this way impacts performance, maybe on large sets or inc ase you have a lot of them it may NOT be the best approach..

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const myCloneSet = new Set(Array.from(mySet));
console.log(mySet === myCloneSet) //false
```

Answer (score -2):

If the Map contains non-nested structures (e.g. Map of Arrays), here's a quick way to deep copy it, for anyone interested:

```
const newMap = new Map();
old.forEach((val, key) => newMap.set(key, [...old.get(key)]));
```

Comment: OP asked for a shallow clone though

Comment: Sure, but if you look in the comments, some people came looking for a way to deep clone. I did too, but didn't find an answer for what I came for, so I added an answer for whoever might be interested.

Comment: The top answer is good, so no need for me to repeat the same thing