# How to shallow copy a Set in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, set, ecmascript-5

I haven't used Sets very much, even though I'm familiar with Object/Array references and the need for shallow copies:

```
const originalObject = { foo: 'bar' };
const clonedObject1 = Object.assign({}, originalObject);
const clonedObject2 = { ...originalObject };

const originalArray = ['bar'];
const clonedArray1 = originalArray.slice();
const clonedArray2 = [ ...originalArray ];
```

I'm using React and need a `new Set()` to setState without mutating and re-using the same reference.

How can I perform a shallow copy or slice a `new Set()`?

Comment: See this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626070/shallow-clone-an-es6-map-or-set)

Comment: @GriffinSuparto thanks, for some reason Google couldn't recommend that article....

Comment: It is the top match when you search for the exact title of your question.