# How do I correctly clone this Map?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, cloning

In my React app, at one point I'm trying to copy a Map from an object, but it's not working for me.

The initial user object has the structure:

user: {
videoTracks: Map,
... other fields...
}

If I do a console log on user, I get this for videoTracks:

[image]

Then I do this: `const newVideoTracks = user.videoTracks;`

and I would expect newVideoTracks to be the same as the first image, but instead I get the following:

[image]

It has 2 entries and size:2, but it says Map(1) at the top.

I know the console isn't always accurate, but in this case when I subsequently use newVideoTracks, it behaves as though there is only 1 entry.

I assume I need to do some cloning rather than just copying it, so I tried both of the following:

`const newVideoTracks = new Map(user.videoTracks);` - this didn't make any difference

`const newVideoTracks = Object.assign({}, user.videoTracks)` - caused a crash

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: How does this map being modified? Is it possible it's getting modified in async?

Comment: Yes, I guess so - it's modified by a library, so I don't know the details.

Comment: In that case perhaps one of these methods will help cloning the map: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626070/shallow-clone-a-map-or-set