# Split string into an object javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this string.

```
'"pen pineapple" apple pen "pen pen"'
```

Is there a good way to convert it into an object which would look like this:

```
{
a: "pen pineapple",
b: "apple",
c: "pen",
d: "pen pen"
}
```

I am looking for a solution in pure javascript!

Comment: Can you show us a `bad` way to do it?

Comment: Even if we can get an array like- ["pen pineapple", "apple", "pen", "pen pen"], i can do the rest.

Comment: @TânNguyễn that is what i am trying currently. But i hope some will come up with a shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting strings that have quotes...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647776/2725684

Then converting that array into an object...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215753/2725684

So, when you combine these answers, it looks like this...

```
var myRegexp = /[^\s"]+|"([^"]*)"/gi;
var myString = '"pen pineapple" apple pen "pen pen"';
var myArray = [];

do {
    var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
    if (match != null) {
        myArray.push(match[1] ? match[1] : match[0]);
    }
} while (match != null);

var obj = myArray.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[i] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an adapted version of [Split a string by commas but ignore commas within double-quotes using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457952/1447675) and use [`Number#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method for the keys.

```js
var str = '"pen pineapple" apple pen "pen pen"',
    arr = str.match(/(".*?"|[^" \s]+)(?=\s* |\s*$)/g),
    object = {};

arr.forEach(function (a, i) {
    object[(i + 10).toString(36)] = a.replace(/"/g, '');
})    

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient function but does what you need (returns array)

```
function splitter(inputString) {
    var splitted = inputString.split(' ');
    var out = []
    var temp = "";
    var quoteStarted = false;

    for (i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {

        if (splitted[i].indexOf('"') > -1 && !quoteStarted) {
            temp += splitted[i] + " ";
            quoteStarted = true;
        } else if (quoteStarted && splitted[i].indexOf('"') == -1) {
            temp += splitted[i] + " ";
        } else if (quoteStarted && splitted[i].indexOf('"') > -1) {
            temp += splitted[i];
            out.push(temp);
            quoteStarted = false;
            temp = "";
        } else {
            out.push(splitted[i])
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in pure javascript like this way

```
let str = '"pen pineapple" "apple" "pen" "pen pen"'
let obj = {}
let pattern = /".*?"/g;
let index = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
let i=0
let key

while(current = pattern.exec(str))
 {
   key = index[i]
   obj[key] = current[0].replace('"','')
   i++
 }

console.log(obj)
```