# Split string by spaces but ignore spaces in quotation marks

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string, any string, into an array by spaces, preferably with the `split()` method. However, I wish to ignore spaces in quotation marks.

Take, for example:

```
'word "words in double quotes"'
```

It should become an array with:

```
[
  'word',
  'words in double quotes'
]
```

I looked at similar answers to this, and they usually gave an array with:

```
[
  'word',
  '"words in double quotes"'
]
```

and that isn't what I'm looking for. I don't want the quotation marks added into the array element.

What regular expression could I use?

Comment: it's impossible with `split` alone as `split` can't remove the final quotation mark without, well introducing another split. Try e.g. `const [match, first, second] = string.match(/^(.*) "(.*)"$/)`

Comment: maybe `'word "words in double quotes"'.split(/"(.*?)"|\s+/g).filter(Boolean)`, but depends on how quotes within the quotes are escaped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript split string on space or on quotes to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817646/javascript-split-string-on-space-or-on-quotes-to-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you want can be achieved through the use of [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) alone, because its use will most likely lead to empty strings in the resulting array; and that's about the string you gave. If you need a general solution to your problem I believe `split` won't work at all.

If your goal is to produce the same result irrespective of the actual string, I'd suggest you use a combination of [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), [`[].map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) as shown:

**Code:**

```js
var
  /* The string. */
  string = 'apples bananas "apples and bananas" pears "apples and bananas and pears"',

  /* The regular expression. */
  regex = /"[^"]+"|[^\s]+/g,

  /* Use 'map' and 'replace' to discard the surrounding quotation marks. */
  result = string.match(regex).map(e => e.replace(/"(.+)"/, "$1"));
  
console.log(result);
```

---

**Explanation of the regex used:**

- `"[^"]+"`: Capture any sequence of characters *(at least 1)* inside two quotation marks except a quotation mark.
- `|`: Logical OR.
- `[^\s]+`: Capture any sequence of non-whitespace characters *(at least 1)*.
- `g`: The global flag - instruction to match all occurrences.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for the `word "words with double quotes"` string to act as an example. The regular expression should work with any string, such as `command arg1 "arg 2" arg3` or `apples bananas "apples and bananas"`

I fixed the wording in the post to clear up any confusion.

Comment: Check out my answer once more @insertcodehere. I have updated it to match any given string. I hope this helps 

Comment: Thanks for all your help! @Angel Politis

Comment: Also, while this is an adequate answer, would it be possible to remove the `map()` method and just somehow implement it into the regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for:

```js
var words = 'word "words in double quotes" more text "stuff in quotes"';
var wordArray = words.match(/"([^"]+)"|[^" ]+/g);
for(var i=0,l=wordArray.length; i<l; i++){
  wordArray[i] = wordArray[i].replace(/^"|"$/g, '');
}
console.log(wordArray);
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, it works fine. I also did a jsbench and this one is faster too. this should be the accepted answer, not the one by Angel Politis

Answer (score 0):

1. split initial string by "
2. split each odd item in result of #1 by space

using regexp dramatically affects readability and maintainability of your code. especially when your are trying to make workaround about existing limitations(say, lacking look behind).